# How can I select descriptions from a database?

Tags: ms-access, select, textbox, sql-like

I'm trying to select some descriptions from database using control source field (list box) based on a text box (txtUIDMaszyny)

```
SELECT [tblOpisy_Awarii].[ID], [tblOpisy_Awarii].[Opis_Awarii] FROM tblOpisy_Awarii WHERE [tblOpisy_Awarii].[UID] LIKE """ & Me!txtUIDMaszyny  & """;
```

But I get no result. If I type manually `LIKE 'MSZ'`, for example, it will return the values.

What am I doing wrong?

txtUIDMaszyny also collects info from the other form, but it shows fine. Code of that textbox:

```
=[Forms]![formMaszynyObszar1]![listListaMaszyn].[Column](1)
```

Comment: @KenWhite It's a common paradigm in SQL to write keywords in all caps.

Comment: What do You mean shouting? I always put stuff like WHERE or LIKE using capital leters, its no shouting, just a way of typing. Sorry if that felt like shouting :)

Comment: @Tyler: In what SQL dialect are ACCESS CONTROL SOURCE keywords?

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't say it made sense, just offering a reason for why Eska is in all-caps mode.

Comment: @BobKaufman Like should include suitable wildcards

Comment: Sorry, used to type such things as capital letters, no meaning of shouting on anybody :x

Comment: Eska, [Column](1) is not the same as Column(0), the bound column and the value of the control. If you want [Column](1), you must say so in your statement.

Comment: I'ts about SELECT [tblOpisy_Awarii].[ID], [tblOpisy_Awarii].[Opis_Awarii] FROM tblOpisy_Awarii WHERE [tblOpisy_Awarii].[UID] LIKE """ & Me!txtUIDMaszyny  & """; code: =[Forms]![formMaszynyObszar1]![listListaMaszyn].[Column](1) works good, returns column value.

Comment: Which column contains the data you would like to match? Do not use LIKE when you mean =, like involves wildcards.

Comment: Looks like you want `SELECT [tblOpisy_Awarii].[ID], [tblOpisy_Awarii].[Opis_Awarii] FROM tblOpisy_Awarii WHERE [tblOpisy_Awarii].[UID] = """ & Me!txtUIDMaszyny.Column(1) & """"`

Comment: [Forms]![formMaszynyObszar1]![listListaMaszyn].[Column](1) this contains value I want to put in this query. This value is in txtUIDMaszyny as well.
That really doesnt matter from where I'll get it as long as I'll just get it. @Fionnuala that doesn't return any values as well.

Comment: Please see my last two comments.

Comment: I am confused, why txtUIDMaszyny and listListaMaszyn? Which one do you want?

Comment: @Fionnuala still no results, even with SELECT [tblOpisy_Awarii].[ID], [tblOpisy_Awarii].[Opis_Awarii] FROM tblOpisy_Awarii WHERE [tblOpisy_Awarii].[UID] = """ & Me!txtUIDMaszyny.Column(1) & """

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88598/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-eska).

Comment: this value is in both of it, so lets say i want the value from [Forms]![formMaszynyObszar1]![listListaMaszyn].[Column](1)